# Disable Debugging symbols in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

How to disable debugging symbols in VS2008.

I'd unchecked "load symbols ..." in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols but directories as ".pdb" and file pingme.txt still appear in my project folders.

Comment: Who is pingme.txt? Do you want to disable symbol generation or loading?

Comment: Just empty file pingme.txt in my project folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which symbols are appearing? You will still get them for your code unless you disable them in project settings.

Also check environment variable `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` is not set.

Comment: _NT_SYMBOL_PATH= symsrv*symsrv.dll*f:\localsymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

Comment: > Which symbols are appearing?
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.pdb\
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.pdb\
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.pdb\
mscorlib.pdb\
System.Configuration.pdb\
System.Data.OracleClient.pdb\
System.Data.pdb\
System.Design.pdb\
System.Drawing.pdb\
System.EnterpriseServices.pdb\
System.pdb\
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.pdb\
System.Transactions.pdb\
System.Windows.Forms.pdb\
System.Xml.pdb\
vshost.pdb\
Some this

Comment: If that environment variable is set and Options | Debugging | Symbols is empty, then VS will use the value of `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` to find symbols. Both need to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Well not from there.

Go in Project Properties > Compile Tab > Advanced Compile Options (button)

After that you will have a combo box(Generate Debug Info) and select None